# Find local minima in neighborhood in 3D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to implement the SIFT algorithm. I have a matrix, say D, of dimension (3, m, n). For each point in the middle layer in the matrix, i.e. in A(2,:,:) (Matlab is 1-indexed), I need to find the local minima in the 3x3 neighborhood of the point. The way I'm doing it is a very naive way as follows:

```
img = D(2, :, :);
for r = 2:size(img, 1)-1
    for c = 2:size(img, 2)-1
        nbr = D(:, (r-1):(r+1), (c-1):(c+1));
        if abs(D(2,r,c) - min(nbr(:))) <= eps(0.5) || abs(D(2,r,c) - max(nbr(:))) <= eps(0.5)
            x = [x; r];
            y = [y; c];
        end
    end
end
```

But this computation is excruciatingly slow. Is there anyway to do this faster?

Comment: In your `if`, you are comparing `D(r,c)` and `min(nbr(:))` However, `nbr` contains `D(r,c)` which is `D(1, r, c)`. Does your code gives you correct answer? I guess it will just gives you empty array.

Comment: You're right. It gave me an error. It's D(2,r,c)

Comment: That still does not give right answer. Maybe you want `D(2,r,c)>min(nbr(:))` which means 'center is not the minimum'

Comment: I've made one more edit. I am trying to find out if the point is a local minima. D(2,r,c) is the point of interest. min(nbr(:)) gives the minimum of the neighborhood. abs(D(2,r,c) - min(nbr(:))) < eps(0.5) basically checks if the two values are close together. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox? There are several functions in there that will do this in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this code:

```
Nr = size(D, 2); Nc = size(D, 3);
[r0,c0] = meshgrid(-1:1, -1:1);
[r,c]   = meshgrid(2:Nr-1, 2:Nc-1);
r = r(:);
c = c(:);

nbr1 = squeeze(D(1, :, :));
nbr2 = squeeze(D(2, :, :));
nbr3 = squeeze(D(3, :, :));
ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,r,r0(:)') + (bsxfun(@plus,c,c0(:)')-1)*Nr;
nbr0 = nbr2(r + (c-1)*Nr);
nbrx = [nbr1(ind1), nbr2(ind1), nbr3(ind1)];

condition = abs(nbr0-min(nbrx,[],2)) <= eps(0.5) | abs(nbr0-max(nbrx,[],2)) <= eps(0.5);

x = r(condition);
y = c(condition);
[x,y]
```

It should be faster for large matrices.

To avoid the `squeeze` function, reorder indices (`dimension (m, n, 3)` instead of `dimension (3, m, n)`). Thus:

```
Nr = size(D, 1); Nc = size(D, 2);

nbr1 = D(:, :, 1);
nbr2 = D(:, :, 2);
nbr3 = D(:, :, 3);
```